# How to extract Asterisk (*) value in pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have a file which contains special characters, I am using extract function to extract each field from the file. I use regex pattern in extract function to extract data. My input file has data like this

`023450123562389MEV120846320134*-000000.0006/03/2012`

My query is like

```
b=foreach a generate flattern(EXTRACT(a,'([\\w\\s]{05})([\\w\\s]{10})([\\w\\s]{02})([\\w\\s]{01})([\\w\\s]{10})([\\w\\s\\W]{01})([\\w\\s\\W]{10})([\\w\\s]{10})'))
```

This query fails and I didn't get an answer for this.

I am not able to extract `*` as a value from the file, as `*` is a metacharacter and it has it's specific value in regex.

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with `\*`

Answer (score 1):

You can either put it in the character class at the point where you want to allow the special character (you don't need to escape `*` in a character class) or you can escape special characters by using a `\`.

Example:

```
[\\w\\s*]
```

or

```
[\\w\\s]{5}\\*
```

For more details on which characters needs escaping, see [Special Characters on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special)

OK, I had a closer look at your regex, and your problem is not the `*` this is matched by this group

```
([\\w\\s]{05})([\\w\\s]{10})([\\w\\s]{02})([\\w\\s]{01})([\\w\\s]{10})([\\w\\s\\W]{01})([\\w\\s\\W]{10})([\\w\\s]{10})
                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because you allow `\W` non word characters.

Your problems are the dot and the slashes in the last part, since that group

```
([\\w\\s]{05})([\\w\\s]{10})([\\w\\s]{02})([\\w\\s]{01})([\\w\\s]{10})([\\w\\s\\W]{01})([\\w\\s\\W]{10})([\\w\\s]{10})
                                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

allow only word characters and whitespace.

But the question is: What do you want to achieve? I am quite sure there is a simpler regex for this. At least the `\s` can be deleted from classes having `\W`.